# PHP - Session inaccessible on other pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a website samplewebsite.com, and the log in function and session are working fine.

Now I am creating a new page involving the session started at the log-in page, which is located at samplewebsite.com/sample.php. The file only contains the following code for now.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION)){
print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

This outputs an empty array. When I check Chrome's developer tools, the Cookies tab include a PHPSESSID which I presume means that a session has actually been started.

I am terribly frustrated why at my samplewebsite.com I am logged in and the session is picked up properly while at samplewebsite.com/sample.php I can't get the session I need at all.

Is there some kind of error in the server's session configuration? What could have gone wrong or what are the possible causes of this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is a snippet of my login file.

```
include "db.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start(); }   

if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])){header("Location: /"); }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $query = mysql_query("Select * from users where `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' and `password`='".md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']))."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['ID'];

        header("Location: /"); exit();


    }
    else{

        echo "<script>alert('Account Invalid')</script>";

    }


}
```

The session has been init because if not I would be redirected to the login page(because of the redirect function on index.php where if $_SESSION['admin'] is not set, redirect to login). This is tested by manually deleting the session on chrome's dev tool and refreshing the page will take me the login page.

So I am logged in and I see my session working on samplewebsite.com , but on my other tab at samplewebsite.com/sample.php, I can't echo out $_SESSION['admin'] when I try

```
echo $_SESSION['admin'];
```

Comment: If you don't put anything inside the session, it will be empty.

Comment: Where you set your session variables ???

Comment: enable error_reporting and display_errors on, make sure that no output was send before you call session_start()

Comment: Sorry about the missed details. 
The session was set at the login page where after a simple validation
$_SESSION['admin'] = $id;

Comment: set session variable like $_SESSION['val'] = 'Something'. now check it shows value.

Answer (score 0):

The SESSION array is empty by default, you have to init your variables.

for example:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'my test';

if(isset($_SESSION)){
print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

Then you will see 'my test' output.
Don't forget to init session in each php page to be able to access your vars.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start(); }
```

just

```
session_start();
```

on EACH page at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not be an appropriate answer, I now have an idea why I couldn't pick up the session.

As I was looking at the chrome's dev tool's Cookies tab. I have noticed that the sessions are stored in different domains. Probably because I logged in at

```
http://www.samplewebsite.com/login.php
```

where the session was stored in a domain named

```
www.samplewebsite.com
```

While I was trying to access the session from

```
samplewebsite.com/sample.php
```

Whose sessions were based at domain

```
samplewebsite.com
```

I completely overlooked the URLs which was a stupid mistake of mine, I am completely blind about the difference between the two domains and maybe just lacked the general knowledge or so.

Thanks for your quick responses.